# Using various input files for fields in Python Requests

Tags: python, google-maps, python-requests

I am sending queries to Google's directions API. From another programme, I am generating origin and destination latitude and longitude coordinates. I am currently saving these in CSV's files in this structure

```
Y,X,
51.516185371445459,-0.102373799765274,
51.512892732882598,-0.083154776597858,
51.514087813699639,-0.097131850779755,
```

I am using the fantastic python Requests to generate these queries, but cannot work out how to specify in the fields, a look up to these csv files I have created. I am using the following -

```
>>> import json, requests
>>> params = {'origin': '*directory to csv location*', 'destination': '*directory to csv location*', 'key': '*key*'}
>>> r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json', params=params)
>>> print(r.url)
```

How do I tell the requests where the file is and what fields within the CSV to use? For the API, the coordinates need to be entered without comma's or spaces, so I would need to carry out this manipulation too.

Perhaps there is a better way than using CSV's?

Comment: You cannot just pass a CSV file to the API, no. You can easily read the data from the CSV with the `csv` module though. Did you read up on the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to see what parameters the API takes?

Comment: What coordinates are the origin and the destination here?

Comment: Many thanks! I have the origin and destination coordinates in two separate CSV. Would I be better to put them in one CSV and put them in different columns? 
I don't have any waypoints, so that simplifies things.

Comment: Depends on how you want to combine them. If it is a straight-up start - end pairing, you can put them in one file, or you can use `zip()` to pair up the rows (`for start, end in zip(start_reader, end_reader):`).

Comment: I shall try the straight up start and end pairing and see how I go! Many thanks. I shall try and get this to work

Comment: I just worked out how to accept answers! Done ;-)
I actually have another query, Sorry! Im trying to run in IDLE, but it is saying that it cannot find the requests library. It does, however, work in Terminal. Ive just realised that in terminal I am running 2.7.5 and in IDLE 3.4.1. Can you advise what I should do? I prefer the colour coding of the code in IDLE!

Comment: Usually, IDLE is installed for *both* Python versions. You can easily install `requests` for Python 3.4.1 too. IT depends on your platform a bit, and how things are installed. There are plenty of questions about both IDLE and installing packages into different Python installations here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, got that sorted. Ive encountered a second issue... When I use the same code, only to specify the 3rd and 4th field in the csv, the script wont pick up the destination coords. I believe Im making a mistake somewhere here -  

origincoords = ['{Y1}{X1}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
destinationcoords = ['{Y2}{X2}'.format(**row) for row in reader]

I also tried -

destinationcoords, origincoords = [('{Y2}{X2}'.format(**row),('{Y1}{X1}').format(**row) for row in reader]

But no luck. Any advice? Thank you ;)

Comment: Right, you cannot loop over the reader twice, not without resetting the read position of the file back to the start.

Comment: You'd do `coords = [('{Y1}{X1}'.format(**row), '{Y2}{X2}'.format(**row)) for row in reader]` for one list of tuples; you can then unpack in a loop with `for source, dest in coords:`.

Comment: You are so helpful. So, I tried this...

>>> with open('/V1.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    coords = [('{Y1}{X1}'.format(**row), '{Y2}{X2}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
              for source, dest in coords:
              'origin'
              'destination'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [Google Maps API webservice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), nor `requests` take CSV filenames. You'll have to read the data from the CSV file first, then pass the values to the API. You can use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for this instead:

```
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'
apikey = '*key*'

with open('csv_filename', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    coords = ['{X},{Y}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
    start, waypoints, end = coords[0], coords[1:-1], coords[-1]
    params = {'origin': start,
              'waypoints': '|'.join(waypoints),
              'destination': end,
              'key': apikey}
    directions = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
```

Here, the `DictReader()` will take the first row as keys, so each column can be addressed as `X` and `Y`, respectively. I then just format those into a string Google can understand.

I've assumed that the CSV file represents a series of points to get directions for; start, waypoints and end.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import requests
>>> sample = '''\
... Y,X,
... 51.516185371445459,-0.102373799765274,
... 51.512892732882598,-0.083154776597858,
... 51.514087813699639,-0.097131850779755,
... '''
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(sample.splitlines())
>>> next(reader)
{'': '', 'X': '-0.102373799765274', 'Y': '51.516185371445459'}
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(sample.splitlines())
>>> coords = ['{X},{Y}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
>>> start, waypoints, end = coords[0], coords[1:-1], coords[-1]
>>> params = {'origin': start,
...           'waypoints': '|'.join(waypoints),
...           'destination': end,
...           'key': 'someapikey'}
>>> params
{'destination': '-0.097131850779755,51.514087813699639', 'waypoints': '-0.083154776597858,51.512892732882598', 'key': 'someapikey', 'origin': '-0.102373799765274,51.516185371445459'}
>>> url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'
>>> directions = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(directions)
{'routes': [], 'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'}
```

In this specific case, your coordinates do not actually result in a viable route, so `'status': 'ZERO_RESULTS'` is returned.